# Is the integral of a continuous function of two variables with respect to one of them a continuous function of the other?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(x,y)$ is continuous, is $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dy$ continuous wherever it is defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not (at least not neccessarily). We can construct a continuous function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ such that $F(x) = 1$ for $x>0$, $F(x) = -1$ for $x<0$ and $F(0) = 0$ by letting $f(x, y)$ for a fixed $x$ have a bump that moves further out to infinity as $x$ goes to $0$. For instance,
$$
f(x, y) = \cases{\frac1{\sqrt\pi}e^{-(y + 1/x)^2} & if $x>0$\\
 0 & if $x = 0$\\
 -\frac1{\sqrt\pi}e^{-(y + 1/x)^2} & otherwise}
$$